# How operators work in expression priority-wise?

Tags: c

I am confused with this expression:
if `x=20`, `y=10`, `z=5` (all integer) then
`(x*z/z-y)` should be `-10` right?

But when I run this expression in VS Code, it gives 10 as a result!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=20,y=10,z=5;
    printf("\n%d",x*z/z-y);
}
```

Comment: `x*z/z-y` equals `x-y`, which is `20-10`.  That''s 10, not -10.  So, yes, of course it gives 10.  `x` is greater than `y`.

Comment: This is actually a (really basic) math question. You always calculate the multiplication and division operators first and the addition and subtraction operators second. Please read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about fundamental math, not programming. There is no difference between the C expression `x*z/z-y` and the math equivalent.

Comment: yeah i am sorry ! i was really confused because i massed 20/20=1 and mixed two different topics my college teacher taught me ! i tried to delete it but i couldn't ! ( i think we all have those moments when we are confused and when we realized we laugh XD )

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication and division have the same precedence and they group left to right, and they both have higher precedence than subtraction.  So the expression parses like this:

```
((x*z)/z)-y
```

So you have ((20*5)/5)-10 == (100/5)-10 == 20-10 == 10.